# PostgreSQL interval error

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to run the following query. Not  sure, what mistake I am doing:

```
select min(p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE p.timezone AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles' ) as Date,
 'America/Los_Angeles' AS Timezone, sum(GREATEST(0, p.value)) as Value  
from main.production_m p 
where 
p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE p.timezone >= '2017-02-18' 
and p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE  p.timezone < '2017-02-22' + INTERVAL '1 day'
```

Getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type interval: "2017-02-20"
LINE 5: ...and p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE  p.timezone <= '2017-02-2...
```

Appreciate your input.
Thanks
Karthey

Comment: `**'2017-02-22'**`  what are these asterixes doing there?

Comment: I removed it just now

Comment: `'2017-02-22' + INTERVAL ('1 day')` or `'2017-02-22' + INTERVAL '1 day'::interval`

Comment: Its working after adding parentheses.. Thanks Nicarus!

Answer (score 1):

PSQL thinks that your date should be an interval for some reason; you can fix this by casting:

```
p.start_timestamp AT TIME ZONE  p.timezone < '2017-02-22'::timestamptz + INTERVAL '1 day'
```

Comment: "Some reason": the reason is point 2.a. of the PostgreSQL [operator type resolution rules](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-oper.html).